# What is the limit of vanishing density?

Tags: thermodynamics

I've been asked to examine the limit of vanishing density for the virial equation of state derivation of $\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T$ and quite frankly, I have no idea what this is and a Google search doesn't seem to net anything extremely helpful.

Assuming density can be isolated in my derivation above, am I just taking the limit as $\rho \rightarrow 0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit of vanishing density or vanishing anything, for that matter, is when you take the limit of what your examining as said property goes to infinity.  In this case:

$$\lim_{\rho \to \infty}{\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T}$$